# android: honor 7 phone does not receive Boot Complete or WakefulBroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I have written an android app which has to start working on startup or keep working after closing the app (swiping it away). This works fine on an emulator or on my p8 phone but I do not know why honor 7 is not able to do so. I mean at the early stages of developing it was working but now it does not. after swipping away I will see this log:

```
05-08 21:45:55.260    3608-3608/? I/HwSystemManager﹕ ProcessTrimService:huawei.intent.action.hsm_remove_pkg received, pkg name is com.example.happyuser.newmap
05-08 21:45:55.260   3608-10168/? I/HwSystemManager﹕ ProcessManager:trimApps, before filter pkgList:[com.example.happyuser.newmap]
05-08 21:45:55.270   3608-10168/? I/HwSystemManager﹕ SmcsDbHelper:getAppProtectStateFromDb called, pkg is:com.example.happyuser.newmap
05-08 21:45:55.280   3608-10168/? I/HwSystemManager﹕ ProcessManager:trimApps, after filter pkgList:[com.example.happyuser.newmap]
05-08 21:45:55.280   3608-10168/? I/HwSystemManager﹕ ProcessManager:forcestopApp begin!! pkgs = [com.example.happyuser.newmap]
05-08 21:45:55.280   3608-10168/? I/HwSystemManager﹕ ProcessManager:forcestopApp : com.example.happyuser.newmap
05-08 21:45:55.520    3384-3518/? W/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '35c63073 com.example.happyuser.newmap/com.example.happyuser.newmap.MapsActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
05-08 21:45:55.520    3384-3518/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '35c63073 com.example.happyuser.newmap/com.example.happyuser.newmap.MapsActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
05-08 21:45:55.520    3384-3404/? W/InputDispatcher﹕ Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '35c63073 com.example.happyuser.newmap/com.example.happyuser.newmap.MapsActivity (server)'
05-08 21:45:58.280    3384-3411/? I/PG Utils﹕ startservice pkg:[com.example.happyuser.newmap] pid:[26989] send to pg
```

In my other huawi phone (P8) I run again my app and swipe it away then the below log shows up and after a little time my apps start over working.

```
05-08 21:53:19.390    3758-3758/? I/HwSystemManager﹕ ProcessTrimService:huawei.intent.action.hsm_remove_pkg received, pkg name is com.example.happyuser.newmap
05-08 21:53:19.390    3758-7856/? I/HwSystemManager﹕ ProcessManager:trimApps, before filter pkgList:[com.example.happyuser.newmap]
05-08 21:53:19.400    3758-7856/? E/HwSystemManager﹕ CheckProtectedAppPredicate:input.getPackageName() = com.example.happyuser.newmap; should not be killed; protect
```

can you give me some idea to solve my problem?